# Odoo workflow not in state draft on create

Tags: xml, odoo, workflow, transition

I've made a custom workflow where I included two states: draft, done.
My model only goes in state draft after I save it or click a random button on the form.
I added the flow_start attribute, thinking this will fix this, but no results.

This is my workflow code:

```
<openerp>
<data>
<!-- maatwerk order workflow -->

    <record id="mw_workflow" model="workflow">
        <field name="name">mw.workflow</field>
        <field name="osv">maatwerk.order</field>
        <field name="on_create">True</field>
    </record>

    <record id="activity_draft" model="workflow.activity">
        <field name="wkf_id" ref="mw_workflow"/>
        <field name="flow_start">True</field>
        <field name="name">draft</field>
    </record>
    <record id="activity_done" model="workflow.activity">
        <field name="wkf_id" ref="mw_workflow"/>
        <field name="flow_stop">True</field>
        <field name="name">done</field>
        <field name="kind">function</field>
       <field name="action">done()</field>
    </record>

    <record id="trans_draft_done" model="workflow.transition">
        <field name="act_from" ref="activity_draft"/>
        <field name="act_to" ref="activity_done"/>
        <field name="signal">draft_done</field>
    </record>   

</data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information? Why shouldn't state just default to 'draft' like in so many examples. And don't mix up activity fields name and function (activity_done seems just wrong or not finished)

Comment: Yes that is what I want, that default starting state is 'draft', but for some reason he starts in no state, after I click save or something he jumps to the state draft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two easy possibilities to get default values in Odoo:

1. ORM Model _defaults (V7+)

   ```
   class ModelX(orm.Model):
       _name = 'model.x'
       _columns = {'state':fields.selection([('draft','Draft'),('done','Done')], string='State')}
       _defaults = {'state':'draft'}
   ```
2. Field default (V8+):

   ```
   class ModelX(models.Model):
       _name = 'model.x'
       field_x = fields.Selection([('draft','Draft'),('done','Done')], string='State', default='draft')}
   ```

With one of these solutions your model entries should have state 'draft' after creation.